# Proof that $\sqrt X$ doesn't tend to a limit as $X$ tends to infinity

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification

I'm doing a proof by contradiction to show that $\sqrt X$ doesn't tend to a limit. I know there's already a proof on here but it didn't make sense to me so I thought I'd do a different one.

Is this ok what I've done?

[image]

Comment: Everything you did seems mostly sound.

Comment: This really isn't a proof by contradiction at heart, all you just said can be translated to: for all $L>0$ we have some $k$ such that $x>k$ implies $\sqrt{x}>L+1$ so $|\sqrt{x}-L|>1$ meaning it can't converge to $L$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have also assumed that

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt x=L$$

And showed that if $x=4u$,

$$L=\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt x=\lim_{u\to\infty}\sqrt{4u}=\lim_{u\to\infty}2\sqrt u=2L$$

Since $u\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$.

Thus,

$$L=2L\implies L=0$$

And since

$$\sqrt{x+\epsilon}>\sqrt x\ \forall\ x,\epsilon>0$$

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt x>\sqrt1=1>L$$

Hence, contradiction!